# Formatting double value= 12.123 using en_US locale is returning currency format as $12.12 instead USD12.12

Tags: java-8

I have a task to format the amount according to the currency specification for multiple currency.
I am trying below logic to format the amount:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class amountFormatter {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double payment = 12.125f;
    Locale US = new Locale ("en","US");
    NumberFormat nfUS = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(US);
    System.out.println("amount in US format: " + nfUS.format(payment));
}
}
```

The output I am getting here is as below:

> amount in US format: **$12.12**

However I need the output as below:

> amount in US format: **USD12.12**

The above code is working fine for other country code is locale like en_JP, en_AE which return me Value as JPY12, AED12.12

Comment: this is predefined to use `$`, can't you append it yourself?

Comment: It's working fine for US as well, because that's the standard for currency used in US locale.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is expected because **DecimalFormat** uses [DecimalFormatSymbols#getCurrencySymbol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#getCurrencySymbol--) to display the currency.

> DecimalFormat.java, ll. 2817
>
> ```
> case CURRENCY_SIGN:
>     if (i<pattern.length() &&
>         pattern.charAt(i) == CURRENCY_SIGN) {
>         ++i;
>         buffer.append(symbols.getInternationalCurrencySymbol());
>     } else {
>         buffer.append(symbols.getCurrencySymbol());
>     }
>     continue;
> ```

To change that behaviour you could extend the class and override the two **format** functions (*parse* as well but it will just delegate):

```
public class CurrencyCodeNumberFormat extends NumberFormat {

  private final NumberFormat format;


  public CurrencyCodeNumberFormat(final NumberFormat format) {
    this.format = format;
  }


  @Override
  public StringBuffer format(double number, StringBuffer result, FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
    final String unmodified = this.format.format(number, result, fieldPosition).toString();
    // here comes the magic.. take the default parse result and search and replace the currency symbol with its currency code
    final String modified = unmodified.replace(this.format.getCurrency().getSymbol(), this.format.getCurrency().getCurrencyCode());

    return new StringBuffer(modified);
  }

  @Override
  public StringBuffer format(long number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
    final String unmodified = this.format.format(number, toAppendTo, pos).toString();
    // here comes the magic.. take the default parse result and search and replace the currency symbol with its currency code
    final String modified = unmodified.replace(this.format.getCurrency().getSymbol(), this.format.getCurrency().getCurrencyCode());

    return new StringBuffer(modified);
  }

  @Override
  public Number parse(String source, ParsePosition parsePosition) {
    return this.format.parse(source, parsePosition);
  }

}
```

Because this aproach uses the decorator pattern (like the Input/OutputStream classes in JavaSE) you simply have to change your

```
NumberFormat nfUS = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(US);
```

to

```
NumberFormat nfUS = new CurrencyCodeNumberFormat(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(US));
```

and you get

> amount in US format: USD12.12